# Can't I use Python and C or C++ at the same time in the vscode?

Tags: python, c++, c, visual-studio-code

Previously, I studied Python using VSCode. After that, I want to use C & C++ too, so I installed other extensions.

I made "launch.json" file, then `.c/.cpp` file run well but `.py` file doesn't run.

If I click the "run" button, they say "Task 'C/C++: g++ build active file' does not found."

This is my "launch.json" file.

```
    {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and Debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            //"cwd": "C:/MinGW/bin",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "gdb에 자동 서식 지정 사용",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

I guess it's because of the "launch.json" file,
so I tried to make one more "launch.json" file at "Python_workspace > .vscode", but I can't.

How can I run the .c and then run the .py?

Below image is my Folder Configuration.

[image]

Just in case, I'll add the "tasks.json" code.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "runner": "terminal",
    "type": "shell",
    "echoCommand": true,
    "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always"
    },
    "tasks": [

        //C++ compile
        {
            "label": "g++ build",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "${file}",
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": {
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        },

        //C compile
        {
            "label": "gcc build",
            "command": "gcc",
            "args": [
                "${file}",
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": {
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        },

        //
        {
            "label": "execute",
            "command": "cmd",
            "group": "test",
            "args": [
                "/C",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you mean C# or C++ ?

Comment: add a Python launch config to your `launch.json` file

Answer (score 0):

All the debugging configurations were stored in the `launch.json` file, you need not create another one in the `.vscoode` folder.

Click the `Add Configuration...` button in the `launch.json`, VSCode will list the alternative configurations. And you need to switch between the different debugging configurations on different conditions, such as debugging different languages.

And you need to comment `"preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file"` in your launch.json file.